# Can you access riverpod from a flutter action?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am wanting to create an action so that the user can either click a button or hit a key to perform an update on a StateNotifier's state (and then update the ui). But I realize after I figure out how to get `Actions`working that I don't have access to WidgetRef or ref so that I can update the provider.

Is it possible to use actions with Riverpod? Would I need to send `ref` to the action or is that too much lifting and against the point?

```dart
class RemoveFileIntent extends Intent {
  const RemoveFileIntent();
}

class RemoveFileAction extends Action<RemoveFileIntent> {
  RemoveFileAction();

  @override
  Object? invoke(covariant RemoveFileIntent intent) {

    // update riverpod StateNotifier's state?

    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two options. You could create your action in a provider, then pass the provider's Ref to the constructor of your object:

```dart
final removeFileActionProvider = Provider(RemoveFileAction.new);

class RemoveFileAction extends Action<RemoveFileIntent> {
  RemoveFileAction(this.ref);

  final Ref ref;

  @override
  Object? invoke(covariant RemoveFileIntent intent) {
    ref.read(provider).doSomething(intent);

    return null;
  }
}
```

Or create your action in a ConsumerWidget/Consumer/ConsumerStatefulWiget, and pass `WidgetRef` instead of `Ref`